# Java: How to create an instance of a generic class that implements an abstract interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface, instance

Right now, I am trying to create an instance of a generic class `BTree<T>` which implements an interface `SSet<T>` which in turn implements `Iterable<T>`
I've deleted the bulk of the code out of the `BTree<T>` class and left only the constructor. Though, if it's essential, I can add the entire code if anyone believes it is helpful. The `BTree<T>` class looks something like this:

```
package assignment2_draft;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class BTree<T> implements SSet<T> {

    //Some methods

    public BTree(int b, Class<T> clz) {
    this(b, new DefaultComparator<T>(), clz);
    }

}
```

In my own class, I am trying to call the `BTree<T>` class and pass an Integer into the generic. In my class, I have:

```
BTree<Integer> myTree=new BTree<Integer>(Integer.class);
```

which has worked in generic classes before, but not this class. I am wondering, am I passing in the parameters right? Or do I need to somehow reference `SSet<T>` when creating an instance of `BTree<T>`

Comment: Implements an ***abstract*** interface? As opposed to what other kind of interface? [JLS §9.1.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.1.1): ***Every** interface is implicitly `abstract`.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor signature is `BTree(int, Class<T>)`

So it would seem you need to do something like

```
SSet<Integer> tree = new BTree<Integer>(2, Integer.class);
```

Notice the reference is an `SSet<>` not a `BTree<>` - you COULD use a `BTree<>` reference there, if you wanted, but in general it's preferable to [program to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/330057) unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: Well, I guess you're much closer in the syntax. Removed mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Constructor which you provided above, accept two value

```
public BTree(int b, Class<T> clz) {
this(b, new DefaultComparator<T>(), clz);
}
```

but you are providing only one,

```
BTree<Integer> myTree=new BTree<Integer>(Integer.class);
```

does do you have any other constructor ,If not then use following

```
int a=5; 
SSet<Integer> myTree=new BTree<Integer>(a,Integer.class);
```